# Is there any way to limit a Gmail watch to only messages added?

Tags: gmail-api

When setting up a watch for a user is there a way to limit the watch to only messages added to the inbox?

Based on the documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) I see that there is the option for INBOX labelId, but I want to limit it to only messages added as well.  We're currently having to handle this by passing 'history/messagesAdded' in the fields string in the subsequent history.list call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately you cannot**. what you have to do is

Get the history when notification arrived. History returns a `json` and it contains a `'messagesAdded'` if new message is added.

You can keep a `predefined array of labels` like below

```
predefinedLabels = ['UNREAD', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'INBOX']
```

Now you can check, `(each is the history json)`

```
 if 'messagesAdded' in each:
    labels = each["messagesAdded"][0]["message"]["labelIds"]
    intersectionOfTwoArrays = list(set(predefinedLabels) & set(labels))
```

Here you get the `intersection of labels`. Now you have to check that with `predefined labels`

```
if set(predefinedLabels) == set(intersectionOfTwoArrays):
     #get the messageId and do what you want
```

> finally you can `filter the notification` as you want!.
>
> It is better to store `histroyId` and update it with every
>   `notification` and use it when you get the `history`. It will help you
>   to get updated history only.

Please note I used `python` when I was building my sever. So above demo code written using `python`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like history.list added a new parameter "historyTypes". If you set that to "messageAdded", the api will only return history records of that type.